# Mapper parsing exception using Laravel & Elasticsearch

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch through Docker using below 2 commands in Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP version 7.3.6

`docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.1.1`

`docker run -d --rm --name search-aol -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e discovery.type=single-node -e http.cors.enabled=true -e http.cors.allow-origin=http://localhost:1358,http://127.0.0.1:1358 -e http.cors.allow-headers=X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization -e http.cors.allow-credentials=true -d docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.1.1`

I followed this [tutorial](https://appdividend.com/2018/06/30/laravel-elasticsearch-tutorial-example/).

**Model**

```php
class Article extends Model
{
    use ElasticquentTrait;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body', 'tags'];

    protected $mappingProperties = array(
        'title' => [
            'type' => 'text',
            'analyzer' => 'standard',
        ],
        'body' => [
            'type' => 'text',
            'analyzer' => 'standard',
        ],
        'tags' => [
            'type' => 'text',
            'analyzer' => "standard",
        ],
    );

    public function getTypeName()
    {
        return 'article_type_name';
    }
}
```

When trying to create an index I receive an exception.

```php
use App\Article;

Route::get('/test', function () {
    Article::createIndex($shards = null, $replicas = null);

    Article::putMapping($ignoreConflicts = true);

    Article::addAllToIndex();

    return view('welcome');
});
```

**elasticquent.php**

```php
return array(
    'config' => [
        'hosts'     => ['localhost:9200'],
        'retries'   => 1,
    ],
    'default_index' => 'laravel_test',
);
```

**My Packages**

```
"php": "^7.1.3",
"elasticquent/elasticquent": "dev-master",
"elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "6.1.0",
```

Below is the error being throw when creating index

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [article_type_name : {_source={enabled=true}, properties={title={analyzer=standard, type=text}, body={analyzer=standard, type=text}, tags={analyzer=standard, type=text}}}]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [article_type_name : {_source={enabled=true}, properties={title={analyzer=standard, type=text}, body={analyzer=standard, type=text}, tags={analyzer=standard, type=text}}}]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [article_type_name : {_source={enabled=true}, properties={title={analyzer=standard, type=text}, body={analyzer=standard, type=text}, tags={analyzer=standard, type=text}}}]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Please let me know what the issue is.

Comment: Can you add the mapping that you are trying to create in json format?

Comment: @NishantSaini **class Article** already has the mapping of the fields... isn't that sufficient ?

Comment: @Sharath what is the solution ? I am getting the same error.

Comment: @Javed i haven't got any solution for this...  Kept on hold and let me know if you find anything

Comment: @Sharath sure am trying to finish this ASAP.